# Asymptotic confidence interval for gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, confidence-interval

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a sample from a gamma distribution with parameters $(θ,λ)$. I need to find an asymptotic confidence interval for $θ$ confidence level $α$, When $λ$ is unknown. I don't understand how to get close to this problem, because when constructing an asymptotic confidence interval, you first need to find an asymptotic estimate for the parameter $\theta$:
$$
\sqrt{n}\frac{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - \theta\lambda)}{\sqrt{\theta\lambda}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0, 1)
$$
if $\lambda$ was known, then we could consider $\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\lambda}$ and it will be asymptotic estimate of $\theta$. But what to do in case, when $\lambda$ is unknown? Thank you for help!

Comment: You need to specify the pdf of your gamma distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom looking at the standardised expression, $\theta$ seems to be the shape parameter here and $\lambda$ the scale (not the most common usage) so a density of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\theta) \lambda^\theta} x^{\theta- 1} e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}$

Comment: If you think the mean of the $X_i$ is distributed about $\theta \lambda$ and the variance is distributed about  $\theta \lambda^2$, then one possibility would be to divide the square of the sample mean by the sample variance.  What is interesting about this problem is that errors in estimating $\theta$ are negatively correlated with errors in estimating $\lambda$

Comment: @Henry could you check solution below?

Comment: Why did you change the denominator $\sqrt{\theta}\lambda$ to $\sqrt{\theta\lambda}$.  I am not saying you are wrong to do so, but it would affect my comment to  @StubbornAtom

Comment: @Henry because $\sqrt{\theta}\lambda$ is not right. The right one is $\sqrt{\theta\lambda}$

Comment: There is no single Gamma$(\theta,\lambda)$ distribution without further details. So why don't you make things easier and type out the pdf so that everyone's on the same page?

Comment: @StubbornAtom my fault, sorry

Answer (score 1):

According to comment of @Henry we could consider:
$$
\sqrt{n}\frac{(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\lambda} - \theta)}{\sqrt{\theta\lambda}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0, 1)
$$
then, because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta\lambda$ and sample variance is a consistent estimator of $\theta\lambda^2$. We could write:
$$
\sqrt{n}\frac{(\frac{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^2}{S^2} - \theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0, 1)
$$
Out of here it's not difficult to find confidence interval.